# What does ":-" do in a variable declaration?

Tags: bash

I have been tasked with assuming control over some bash scripts, and looking through them I've come across the following notation:

```
INITPATH=${INITPATH:-"include"}
```

As far as I can tell this does something similar to `a = a || b` and allows the setting of a default value if the environment variable is not set?

I guess I'm just looking for some clarification on this, and whether the ":-" can be broken down or used in other contexts. I've as yet failed to come across it flicking through various Bash documentation.

Comment: The keywords for the bash documentation are "parameter expansion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted.
>    Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

In your example, if `INITPATH` is unset/null, it's set to `include`.

Answer (score 0):

This has most of how you can substitute

```
echo "$\{var}"
echo "Substitute the value of var."


echo "1 - $\{var:-word}"
echo "If var is null or unset, word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change."


echo "2- $\{var:=word}"
echo "If var is null or unset, var is set to the value of word."


echo "5-$\{var:?message}"
echo "If var is null or unset, message is printed to standard error. This checks that variables are set correctly."


echo "3 - $\{var:+word}"
echo "If var is set, word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change."
```